# AWS ACM first time usage

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am intending to use ACM for the first time for Proof of Concept purposes. I read that there is a 30 day free trial with no charges for deploying and provisioning ACM. Is this still valid? BTW, my 12 month free trial subscription is over.

Regards,
Ochen

Comment: ACM certs are free, but can't be exported and can only be used on AWS resources such as Cloudfront and ELBs. "deploying" and "provisioning" are terms that seem confusing here. Are you actually talking about the AWS Certificate Manager?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Yes, i am planning to deploy the ACM Private CA. The ACM pricing page says that from the moment you deploy the ACM, you will be charged a monthly rental of $400. Reading down, it also says there is a free trial period of 30 days. So was wondering if that applies to me?